# multiple user inputs to messagebox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, messagebox

I am trying to incorporate many user inputs (textboxes, comboboxes, DatePicker, etc) into one messagebox that will appear once a button is clicked, but I do not know how to do that all within one messagebox. I only know how to do them separately.

Here is my Button_Click code

```
Dim s, sOut As String
    Dim x As System.Xml.XmlElement = cbEval.SelectedItem

    If x Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("fill in Evaluator")
    Else
        s = "Evaluator Name: {0}"
        sOut = String.Format(s, x.InnerText)
        MsgBox(sOut)


    End If
```

When the user chooses an option from cbEval (combobox) and then clicks the "submit" button, the option they chose is displayed. I am trying to also add DatePicker, CbEval, cbSelfEval, txtSelfComments, cbPeer, txtTotal and txtComments to the same MessageBox but don't know how to add them, especially the DatePicker (calendar). Any thoughts as to how I can add more onto 1 messagebox?

Answer (score 0):

*emphasized text*maybe this

```
    Dim s, sOut As String
    Dim x As System.Xml.XmlElement = cbEval.SelectedItem

    If x Is Nothing _
      Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSelfComments.Text) _
      Or DatePicker.SelectedDate Is Nothing _
    Then
        MsgBox("fill in Evaluator")
    Else

        sOut = String.Format("Evaluator Name: {1}{0}Text2: {2}{0}" +
               "Date3: {3}", Environment.NewLine, x.InnerText, txtSelfComments.Text, DatePicker.SelectedDate.ToString())
        MsgBox(sOut)
    End If
```

for datePicker.SelectedDate.ToString() you can use DateTime Format [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: that will not compile, and the link given is in Cyrillic

Comment: Neither of them seem to compile correctly, and having OR right after an if statement gives a syntax error.

Comment: Corrected. It works right (without your xmlElement in combobox).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
If x Is Nothing _
OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotal.Text) _
OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(CbEval.SelectedText) _
OrElse DatePicker.Value Is Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("fill in Evaluator");
Else
    sOut = String.Format("Evaluator Name: {0}" & Environment.NewLine() & _
           "Text: {1}" & Environment.NewLine() & _
           "CbValue: {2}" & Environment.NewLine() & _
           "Date3: {3}", _
           x.InnerText, txtTotal.Text, cbEval.SelectedText, DatePicker.Value.ToShortDateString())
    MessageBox.Show(sOut);
End If
```

When you compare your `DatePicker.Value`, `Nothing` will be the min possible date: `01/01/1900`.